# Помогите разобраться с интерфейсом

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм

При попытке скомпилировать проект возникает ошибка

Error    C2259   'IMilitaryMan': cannot instantiate abstract class   Task12.Tests

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stack>
using std::stack;

class IMilitaryMan 
{
public:
    void virtual Serve() = 0;
    virtual ~IMilitaryMan();
};


class Soldier : public IMilitaryMan
{
private:
    int jobCount;
public:
    Soldier() { this->jobCount = 0; }
    void Serve() override { this->jobCount++; }
};



class Officer : public IMilitaryMan
{
private:
    int countSubordinates = 0;
    int jobCountSended = 0;
    stack <IMilitaryMan> Subordinates;
public:

    Officer(IMilitaryMan* Subordinates, int countSubordinates)
    {
        this->countSubordinates = countSubordinates;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < countSubordinates; i++)
            this->Subordinates.push(Subordinates[i]);
    }

    void Serve() override
    {
        stack<IMilitaryMan> serves;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < countSubordinates; i++)
        {
            Subordinates.top().Serve();
            serves.push(Subordinates.top());
            Subordinates.pop();
        }

        Subordinates = serves;
        jobCountSended++;
    }

    ~Officer()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < jobCountSended; i++)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < countSubordinates; j++)
                Subordinates.top().~IMilitaryMan();

    }
};

int main()
{
    Soldier test;
    IMilitaryMan& militaryMan = test;
    militaryMan.Serve();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И? Действительно, в коде ошибка. Именно такая, как сказал компилятор. В чем ваш вопрос-то?

Comment: да,  во первых  такой стек  stack <IMilitaryMan>  не может существовать, так как не могут существовать обьекты абстрактного класса.

Comment: к вопросу не относится, но суровая, однако, армия получается: при назначении офицера он лично порождает `n` солдат, а при смерти все они совершают ритуальное самоубийство... дважды...

Answer (score -1):

Вы же используете

```
stack <IMilitaryMan> Subordinates;
```

Понятно, что в стеке вы пытаетесь работать именно с `IMilitaryMan`.

Переделайте на

```
stack <IMilitaryMan*> Subordinates;
```

соответствующим образом изменив весь код.

Кстати, даже если бы у вас все сработало - вы би имели неприятности со срезкой.

И еще - вот зачем у вас это?

```
Subordinates.top().~IMilitaryMan();
```

При вашем варианте - хранить не указатели, а объекты - оно явно излишнее.